# Page break inside iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, page-break

I have an iframe and inside the iframe I have some divs with page-break-after:always; style.
when I print the page (ctrl+p) the page-after:always; not working.

What is the reason?
(When i try to print normal page (with no iframe) it successes!)

Thanks.